# PHP How to generate School Year?

Tags: php, mysql

so my codes are:

```
<?php 
$date2=date('Y', strtotime('+1 Years'));
for($i=date('Y'); $i<$date2+5;$i++){
    echo '<option>'.$i.'-'.$date2.'</option>';
}
?>
```

the output is

```
2015-2016
2016-2016
2017-2016
2018-2016
2019-2016
```

I want the output goes like this:

```
2015-2016
2016-2017
2017-2018
2018-2019
2019-2020
```

Any ideas? And i'm trying to put it on a dropbox then save it to my database.

Comment: `echo '<option>'.$i.'-'.($i+1).'</option>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code following way-

```
<?php
    $date2=date('Y', strtotime('+1 Years'));
    for($i=date('Y'); $i<$date2+5;$i++){
        echo '<option>'.$i.'-'.($i+1).'</option>';
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked really well for me.

```php
$years = range('2015', date('Y'), 1);
foreach($years as &$year) {
    $year = $year . '-' . ($year + 1);
}
```

This outputs an array of years from the set year until the current year.